# Documentation for mode-line-emphasis and mode-line-interactive

Tags: faces, themes, mode-line, help, documentation

I'm seeing `mode-line-emphasis` and `mode-line-inactive` used in color themes to change the `mode-line` face value for used and unused buffers.

`describe-function` and `describe-variable` don't have an entry for `mode-line-emphasis` or `mode-line-inactive`

Where can I find information on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are **faces**.

See the Emacs manual, node [Faces](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Faces.html). See node [Faces](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Faces.html) in the Elisp manual to learn about how to investigate and manipulate faces using Emacs Lisp.

Command `list-faces-display` shows you the currently defined faces. You can use command `describe-face` to see a description of a given face, and you can use command `customize-face` to change the appearance of a face.

Comment: `describe-face` and `list-faces-display` were the functions I was looking for, thanks!